# DEBIAN: Show a logfile on TTY1 as default display on physical computer

Tags: linux

OK lets admit you connect a display to a computer that runs linux.
The display will show a login screen asking for user and password.
I am logged in via SSH on pts/0

I can now run a program on TTY1 like this

```
some-program > /dev/tty1 2>&1
```

But what I am looking for is a possibility to just show my console to tty1 without the user to be able to interfere. I tried:

```
screen > /dev/tty1 2>&1
```

but it opened the screen on pts/1 instead ot tty1. I tried

```
top > /dev/tty1 2>&1
```

result was a dark screen
any hint?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [`openvt`](https://manpages.debian.org/kbd/openvt.1) command, present in the [`kbd`](https://packages.debian.org/stable/kbd) package on Debian, deals specifically with using VTs.

For example you can run `top` on `/dev/tty8` with:

```
openvt -c 8 -- top
```

It takes care itself of preparing the correct detached environment for the forked command (redirecting I/Os to the VT, calling  `setsid(2)` etc.) and returns immediately.

I avoided `/dev/tty1` in this example because very often first `/dev/ttyX` are already used to spawn login prompts.

Use [`chvt`](https://manpages.debian.org/kbd/chvt.1) (eg `chvt 8`) if you have to change the VT to be displayed.

You can also choose to not specify the VT and let `openvt` pick the first available, and immediately switch to it using `-s`, So this would work in one shot:

```
openvt -s -- top
```

Be careful to not leave older instances running then...